# How to make an fragment in navigation drawer to not reload when open it again?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want that my fragment don't reload until I stop the service through stop button, my application counts steps through start button and stop counting through stop button. When I click on start button then start button become invisible and stop button becomes visible.
I am working with fragments I use service to  start when I click start button and stop when I click stop button, so my application works in background until i stop it.
But issue is that when I start it and goes to another fragment and come back to that fragment then it reload it and there is start button again, but there should be stop button because I did not stop it, I know because `onCreatView` method calls and activity load again. But I dont want that I want to not reload fragment. 
So how to fix it?

Start and stop button listner in fragment

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class);
                    getActivity().startService(intent);

stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MyService.class);
                getActivity().stopService(intent);
```

myservice class

```
public class MyService extends android.app.Service{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

in manifest

```
<service android:name=".MyService"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

Actually never mind, I just read your question fully. If your only problem is that the buttons show up again after being re-created then forcing your fragment not to reload is not really a good solution.

A really easy thing you could do is to introduce a static variable in your service called `public static boolean isRunning` and then on your Fragment `onResume` method, or `onCreate` method you can simply do something like this:

```
if (MyService.isRunning)
{
    //Hide the start button
}
```

Or you can look more into how to properly detect if a service is running or not via broadcasts.

Comment: is it works navigation drawer activity  because  fragments are in that activity, and in manifest we just declare navigation drawer activity not fragments?

Comment: no its not working , because i can only use this method in navigation drawer activity main file not in fragments, and when i go back to fragment again the instance of fragment was created again

Comment: So your problem is fragments being re-created, not activity being re-created?

Comment: yeah, beacause i work in navigation drawer and all activities are fragments in that

Comment: Your navigation drawer is hosted by an activity, no? "all activities are fragments in that" that doesn't make sense. Either they are activities or fragments.

Comment: oh sorry for that they are fragments in navigation drawer activity i want that fragment is not reloaded when i call it again

Comment: Okay, then you can use the `FragmentManager` backstack instead of creating a new activity. Something like this: `getFragmentManager(_context).popBackStack();`

Comment: but in this case it just hide the start button , it will not continue the tasks that is running by pressing the start button, just like registering sensor and showing their values in real time. i want that not to create new instance of that fragment and continue all working